# How do I send report results to non Salesforce users by email?

Tags: apex, email, reporting, scheduled

I am trying to automate a report by scheduling the report to run at a date/time and emailing the results to mail group.

How do I send report results to mail group?

Apparently via the standard Salesfore functionality that is not possible that is why I need to know is there any other way and workaround to be able to send a scheduled report to mail group?

Comment: Like David mentioned, a possible solution would be to email the report to yourself and then have a forwarding rule on the email client to forward it to the appropriate external emails from there.

Comment: consider Conga Composer (appexchange product)

Answer (score 4):

Classic and Lightning report refresh subscriptions work a little bit differently, but neither is capable of sending a message to an arbitrary email address outside Salesforce. You can email users and groups who have Salesforce accounts for delivery to email addresses that are set on their Salesforce profiles.

Per [Schedule a Report for Refresh](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=reports_schedule.htm&type=5),

> You can send reports only to email addresses included on Salesforce user records.

Per [Subscribe to Get Refreshed Report Results in Lightning Experience](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=reports_subscribe_lex.htm&type=5),

> When the subscription emails the refreshed report to each recipient, it sends to the email address set in Settings | Email | My Email Settings. If no email is set in My Email Settings, then the refreshed report is sent to the recipient’s email address set on their Salesforce User record.

The easiest solution is likely to be a forwarding rule on your corporate email server. Running the report in Apex and generating and sending emails in code would be substantially more complex.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same question and now I'm using a free available [Report Sender app](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000EJdlFUAT) which I could get directly from the Salesforce AppExchange.
There is also a paid upgrade available, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

There is a product called Report Scheduler in appexchange which would let you schedule the reports to the external recipients. You could also pick the file type between excel and pdf while scheduling the report. Following is the product link in appexchange

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=a0N3A00000FMkcdUAD

I am part of the technical team involved in this product development. So please don't just take my word for it. There is a trial period for 28 days, so test it before you take a decision.