# Send Reports to Non Salesforce Users

Tags: apex, visual-workflow, reporting

We want to schedule 8 reports to 15 non-salesforce email addresses every week on Wednesday.

In salesforce, I can see that we cannot send email results to Non-Salesforce users. What is the best way to do this, keeping in mind that the 15 users are likely to grow and change over time and that we will have to schedule more reports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per salesforce out of box functionality, we can't able to send the reports to non salesforce users.

Refer the [Idea](https://ideas.salesforce.com/s/idea/a0B8W00000GdflgUAB/emailing-scheduled-reports-to-other-email-addresses-non-users)

Alternative solution suggested [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/227069/how-do-i-send-report-results-to-non-salesforce-users-by-email)